# Unresolvable dependency resolving within Laravel

Tags: php

I get the error when calling a custom function I created:

```
namespace App\Jobs\Device;

class UpdateUserReference {
    public $installationReference;
    public $userReference;

    // assign payload data and installation id received to command
    function __construct($bodyContent) {
        $this->installationReference = $bodyContent["installationReference"];
        $this->userReference = $bodyContent["userReference"];
    }
}
```

> Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  $bodyContent ]] in class App\Jobs\Device\UpdateUserReference

Strange enough I never had the error before and I create my function exactly the same as for all other cases. What is wrong with the bodyContent variable I provide?

The function is called within:

```
public function update(Request $request) {
    // Get payload from request
    $bodyContent = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    $action = $bodyContent["action"];
    $installationReference = $bodyContent["installationReference"];

    switch($action) {
        case 'userReference':
            $updateUserReference = new UpdateUserReference($bodyContent);
            $result = $this->commandBus->execute($updateUserReference);
            break;
    }

    if (!empty($result)) {
        $response = [
            'error' => [
                'code' => 400,
                'message' => "Update Error"
            ]
        ];

        return $this->setStatusCode(400)->respond($response);
    }

    $response = [
        'data' => [
            'installationReference' => $installationReference
        ]
    ];

    return $this->setStatusCode(201)->respond($response);
}
```